# Using \newcommand in an equation/in math modes

Tags: macros, equations

I found the following command for increasing the space between an `\underline` and its corresponding text:

```
\newcommand{\ovF}[1]{
  $\overline{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+1mm\relax]{#1}}$
}
```

This command works well e.g. in

```
\ovF{a}
```

By trying to overline a term that needs a math environment it works as well, e.g.

```
\ovF{\varphi}
```

However I want to use my command in an equation, e.g.

```
\begin{equation}
  \ovF{a}
  \ovF{\varphi}
\end{equation}
```

Neither the first nor the second line works for me but I couldn't find any reason for this yet. I got the assumption that the predefined math mode of the equation brings me some issues. Therefore I tried to understand those issues by using this command without the equation in a math mode.

```
$\ovF{a}$
$\ovF{\varphi}$
```

Also none of them worked. For all of them I get the same Error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$
```

So my question is: What should I do/change to use my command in a math environment, especially in a equation? Did I make something wrong?

I am sorry if I made any mistakes. I am new to this board and its my first question.

Comment: get rid of the `$` signs in the `\ovF` definition (then it will work exclusively in math mode).  If you, instead, want it to work in both math and non math modes, replace the `$...$` instead with `\ensuremath{...}`.

Comment: Wow, that was easy.. thank you :)
However it doesn't work for \ovF{\varphi}. How can I handle this issue?

Comment: @PeterWita: One would assume you're only using this in math mode, and therefore should use `$#1$` rather than `#1`.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you for your answer. This worked well for me! :)

Comment: That is because the `\varphi` (corresponding to `#1`, shows up inside a `\raisebox`, the contents of which are isolated from the surrounding environment by the box.  Thus, as it stands, `#1` is always set in text mode.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense for me. I updated my answer by a solution. Thank you for your fast help as well! :)

Comment: Please don't put solutions in the question, it just confuses the site structure, you can self-answer by posting an answer rather than editing the question or (as here) just accept a posted answer. (note you are missing `%` in the solution that you give)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my solution. As I mentioned I am new to this board. I will keep it in mind. :)

Answer (score 7):

Generally, a function should be targeted for either math or text mode.  However, since you seem to want something that functions in all modes, I give it a spin, with a bit of overkill.  It obeys math styles, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\ovF}[1]{\ensuremath{%
  \ThisStyle{\overline{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+1mm\relax]{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}%
}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\ovF{a}

\ovF{\varphi} {\LARGE\ovF{\varphi}}

\begin{equation}
  \ovF{a}
  \ovF{\varphi}
\end{equation}

$\ovF{a}$

$\ovF{\varphi} \scriptscriptstyle \ovF{\varphi} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I understand all of it :)